# Doctrine EntityManager find() method returns null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using the [dflydev Doctrine ORM Service Provider](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider) . If I use the `find` method I get `null`.

```
$this->em->find('SilexTemplate\Entity\Theme', $id);
```

The id I am using is 1 and it exists in the database.  If I use the `createQueryBuilder` method I get the entity correctly:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $queryBuilder->select('em')
        ->from('SilexTemplate\Entity\Theme', 'em')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
```

Here is the corresponding Theme entity:

```
<?php
namespace SilexTemplate\Entity;

/**
 * Class Theme
 *
 * @package SilexTemplate\Entity
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity()
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="theme")
 */
class Theme
{
/**
 * The primary key for this entity
 *
 * @var int
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="id")
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * The menu background color
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="menuBackgroundColor", nullable=false)
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="rgba", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $menuBackgroundColor;

/**
 * The menu Font Color
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="menuFontColor", nullable=false)
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="rgba", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $menuFontColor;

/**
 * Is the menu Fixed ?
 *
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="boolean", name="menuFixed", nullable=false)
 */
private $menuFixed;

/**
 * Is the footer Fixed ?
 *
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="boolean", name="footerFixed", nullable=false)
 */
private $footerFixed;

/**
 * The background color
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="backgroundColor", nullable=false)
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="rgba", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $backgroundColor;

/**
 * The font color
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer", name="fontColor", nullable=false)
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="rgba", mappedBy="id")
 */
private $fontColor;

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getMenuBackgroundColor()
{
    return $this->menuBackgroundColor;
}

/**
 * @param int $menuBackgroundColor
 */
public function setMenuBackgroundColor($menuBackgroundColor)
{
    $this->menuBackgroundColor = $menuBackgroundColor;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getMenuFontColor()
{
    return $this->menuFontColor;
}

/**
 * @param int $menuFontColor
 */
public function setMenuFontColor($menuFontColor)
{
    $this->menuFontColor = $menuFontColor;
}

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isMenuFixed()
{
    return $this->menuFixed;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $menuFixed
 */
public function setMenuFixed($menuFixed)
{
    $this->menuFixed = $menuFixed;
}

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isFooterFixed()
{
    return $this->footerFixed;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $footerFixed
 */
public function setFooterFixed($footerFixed)
{
    $this->footerFixed = $footerFixed;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getBackgroundColor()
{
    return $this->backgroundColor;
}

/**
 * @param int $backgroundColor
 */
public function setBackgroundColor($backgroundColor)
{
    $this->backgroundColor = $backgroundColor;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getFontColor()
{
    return $this->fontColor;
}

/**
 * @param int $fontColor
 */
public function setFontColor($fontColor)
{
    $this->fontColor = $fontColor;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any additional code that saves your `find()` method to a variable?  If so can you post that full statement?

Comment: In a other Projekt i use the same code from above but with a other entityname..

Comment: How do you know it is returning `null`?  I don't see you assigning the `find` function to any PHP value.

Comment: I try to use it in twig (The Entity) :p

Comment: Can you then paste the code where you are assigning the entity to a variable and passing it to the Twig template?

Comment: How i use it in twig is not relevant, if i use the queryBuilder it works...
The Problem is the find method..

Comment: The code you have listed would not work because it doesn't assign anything to a variable, if you post your full code then people can help you solve your issue.